# set json data array in function response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax function in response I am getting result but I don't know how to set that response in my page. Is it possible with json_decode or I have to try something else

JSON file is

```
<?php
$group_id = $_POST['group_id'];
$query    = "SELECT *,group_id FROM contact JOIN addressgroup ON addressgroup.contact_id = contact.contact_id WHERE group_id IN (".$group_id.") GROUP BY contact.contact_id";
$res      = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();
$k=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{

  $data[$k][0] = $row['user_id'];
  $data[$k][1] = $row['first_name'];
  $data[$k][2] = $row['middle_name'];
  $data[$k][3] = $row['last_name'];
  $k++;

}
echo json_encode(array($data));
?>
```

AJAX function

```
  var myarray;
  function getcon() {
  myarray = [];
  myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
  $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      url: "getcon.php",
      data: 'group_id=' + myarray.join(),
      success: function(data) {
        totalRecords=data.length;
        zone.fnClearTable();
        for(var i=0; i < (data.length); i++) {
        zone.fnAddData([
          data[k][0],
          data[k][1],
          data[k][2],
          data[k][3],
          ]);
        }
        return false;
      }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You should use `data` instead of `response` in your success function.

Comment: json_encode($data);   instead of json_encode(array($data));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Response is an JSON object..
you have to use it like this:-

replace

```
echo json_encode(array($data));
```

by

```
echo json_encode($data); /* because $data is already an array*/
```

and keep it same as it was earlier

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {

      $data[] = $row['user_id'];
      $data[] = $row['first_name'];
      $data[] = $row['middle_name'];
      $data[] = $row['last_name'];
      $k++;

    }

<script>

 var myarray;
  function getcon() {
  myarray = [];
  myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
  $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "POST",
      url: "getcon.php",
      data: 'group_id=' + myarray.join(),
      success: function(data) {
          console.log(data)/* check the structure of data here*/
          zone.fnClearTable();
          zone.fnAddData([
              data.user_id.,
              data.first_name,
              data.middle_name,
              data.last_name,
          ]);
        return false;
      }
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing name after . operator

Comment: ReferenceError: getcon is not defined

Comment: It means your function "getcon" is not defined are you using getcon function on the same page on which it is defined ?

Comment: There is one other method you can directly return html in ajax response instead of json_encoded data

Comment: I guess now you have edited your question. In the success section you are returning response in 'data' variable and using variable named 'response' in for loop... ?

Comment: Still there is data[k][0] from where you are getting K...?  :)

Comment: ReferenceError: getcon is not defined and SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Answer (score 0):

JSON is an object! Your are getting object, so in your ajax function You must use some loop function like `for` or `$.each` JQuery functions.

```
`success : function (data) {
    $.each (data,function(key,val){
      $("#someId).html(key + " - " + val)
    }
}`
```

Comment: Is your url which in ajax  for php scripts correct url?